# Why is my array of views returning null?

Tags: java, android, arrays, nullpointerexception, view

I have a collection of switches in android; let's call them...

```
Switch one;
Switch two;
Switch three;
Switch four;
Switch five;
```

and I also have an array which contains these views.

```
Switch[] switchArray = {one, two, three, four, five};
```

and then, within my onCreateView() method; I assign all of those Switches using findViewById().

```
one = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchOne);
two = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchTwo);
three = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchThree);
four = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchFour);
five = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchFive);
```

Now; when I create a for-loop to check if that array is null:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<switchArray.length; i++){
      if(switchArray[i] == null){
         Log.d(TAG, "Array is null at:" + i);
     }
    }
```

I get the following logcat:

```
Array is null at: 1
Array is null at: 2
Array is null at: 3
Array is null at: 4
Array is null at: 5
```

and I am unsure as to why these variables are returning null if I tried to instantiate them in onCreate... if I also try to instantiate them before the onCreate (in the class header before any methods); I still get the same error.

Hopefully the problem is clear.

**EDIT 1: FULL ONCREATEVIEW METHOD**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater viewInflation, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle SavedInstantState) {
        superContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        digitalfragmentview = viewInflation.inflate(
                R.layout.digitalfragment_page, container, false);

        digitalIO0Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio0mode);
        digitalIO1Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio1mode);
        digitalIO2Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio2mode);
        digitalIO3Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio3mode);
        digitalIO4Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio4mode);
        digitalIO5Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio5mode);
        digitalIO6Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio6mode);
        digitalIO7Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio7mode);
        digitalIO8Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio8mode);
        digitalIO9Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio9mode);

        // sets the listener for the mode switches
        for (int i = 0; i < digitalIOModeSwitchArray.length; i++) {
            if (digitalIOModeSwitchArray[i] == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Array is null at:" + i);
            }
        }

        return digitalfragmentview;
    }
```

Comment: When are you instantiating switchArray ? You need to instantiate it after you do your "findViewById" calls

Comment: the switchArray is instantiated before the onCreateView(); in the top of the class with all other class variables.

Comment: in my latest edition; digitalIO0Mode is equivalent to Switch One; etc etc...

Comment: You array will not be updated this way. You should instantiate your array after your findViewById calls.

Comment: Okay I will attempt that now and get back to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Switch[] switchArray = {one, two, three, four, five};
```

contains references to `one, two, three, four, five` at the moment you create the array.

Latter, you reassign those variables, but your array still points to the previous references.

You need to create the array after you have assigned your views:

```
one = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchOne);
two = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchTwo);
three = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchThree);
four = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchFour);
five = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchFive);
// Then only
switchArray = {one, two, three, four, five};
```

Comment: Is there a way I can access that array with methods within my class then if it is now out of the scope of other methods within my class?

Comment: did you receive the comment notification?

Comment: you don't need to change it's scope. you can declare it as a member of your class, and still define it in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 2):

First take references to your widget in variables 
`one = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchOne);
two = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchTwo);
three = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchThree);
four = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchFour);
five = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchFive);`

then put them in an array

`Switch[] switchArray = {one, two, three, four, five};`

The reason is that Switch array is value type not reference type

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
one = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchOne);
```

Instead of this..

```
one = findViewById(R.id.switchOne);
```

**EDIT**

```
switchArray[0] = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchOne);
```

Comment: My apologies; I had that already I incorrectly formatted my code. Please refer to my latest update.

Comment: @Tukajo can you post your full `onCreateView()`

Comment: the additions have been made.

Comment: @Tukajo Is that all switches are in `digitalfragment_page.xml`

Comment: Yes; they are all in digitalfragment_page.xml.